# How to make (2) Bar Graph with one overlapping with another one, using JQPlot?

Tags: jqplot

Currently I'm having this code for generating two bars in single graph. But I need to join the two bars (with one overlaps with another). Please help to make code adjustments using JQPlot.

Like in image below, I want the blue graph on the front (which is the array1) the the orange bar (array2) at the back of the blue bar.

[image]

```
  var array1 = ["27", "18", "25", "13", "37", "29", "13", "15", "20"]
  var array2 = ["50", "30", "70", "60", "50", "70", "50", "30", "35"]

        $.jqplot('barChart', [array1, array2], {
            title:'Sales & Marketing',
            animate: true,//!$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
            seriesDefaults:{
                renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                pointLabels: { show: true },
                rendererOptions: {
                  showDataLabels: true
                }
            },
            grid: {
                drawGridLines: true,
                gridLineColor: '#A7A7A7',
                background: '#5F5F5F'
            },
            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    ticks: salesPersonsArray,
                    tickOptions: {
                        showGridline: false,
                        show: true
                    },
                    rendererOptions: {
                        drawBaseline: true
                    }
                },
                yaxis: {
                    showTicks : true,
                    min:10,
                    max:100,
                    tickOptions: {
                        showGridline: true
                    },
                    rendererOptions: {
                        drawBaseline: false
                    }
                }
            },            
            highlighter: { show: false }
        });
```

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a property [stackSeries](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#jqPlot.stackSeries) which can be used with bar charts. This isn't exactly what you want as it puts the each series on top of each other, so using your data you'd end up with the following:

[image]

Note on the first bar the total is 75 as it's added the 2 bars together (25 + 50) whereas you want the blue bar to be 25 and the yellow bar to be 50.

To fix this, you can add a function to loop over your 2 series arrays and create a third array which is the difference between the values in `array2` and `array1`

```
var array3 = [];
$.each(array2, function(k, v) {
    // caclulate new value
    array3.push(array2[k] - array1[k]);
});
```

then on the graph plot the first series (array1, blue) and the new series (array3, yellow). This will result in what you're after:

[image]

See [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vc8ghjyg/1/) for a working demo.

Comment: Hi @Ian A
Thank you very much it works! 
I tried before the stackSeries, but your idea to subtract the arrays value is great. Thank you :)

Comment: And also important thing to convert the array values to integer, otherwise it will not render properly :)

Comment: @aldrien.h Thanks for mentioning that - I'd completely forgot to include that step in my answer :)